# how to change localhost/mysite/web to localhost in bitnami

Tags: apache, symfony, bitnami

how to change localhost/mysite/web to localhost in bitnami

DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.25-0/apache2/htdocs/srd-last/web"

i have configured httpd.conf but it is not working? 
i want to call localhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
     DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.25-0/apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
     ServerName dummy-host.example.com
     ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
     ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
     CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
     DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.25-0/apache2/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
     ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
     ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
     CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

If you look towards the bottom of your http.conf file it has

`Include "/path-to-bitnami-lamp/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`

This overwrites your configuration of virtual hosts so edit virtual hosts there instead.

This problem only exists in newer version and is mentioned in the [documentation](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache#How_to_configure_the_Apache_server.3f) -

> "In recent versions of BitNami apps  the bitnami.conf file defines which configuration for each application should be loaded by the Apache server. This file is located in */installdir/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf*."

Answer (score -1):

DocumentRoot is the path from the root of your Web server (as in the entire file system) to your Web root (The location of where the files that make up your Web page are located)

ServerName is the name you would type into your Web browser.

For a custom ServerName to work you on local host you also need to edit your hosts file.

I think on Windows it's located at C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts